# How do I set the HttpClient proxy?

Tags: java, http, proxy, client

I am trying to create an account checker that loops through a combo list and checks if the account is valid, my problem is that I need to change the proxy every once and a while which is what I am currently struggling with. The problem is that I do not know how to change the proxy in the first place and I have tried countless solutions which did not seem to function.

**Here is my current code that runs without a proxy change**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String requestBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(credentials);
            
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(url))
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
                    .build();


HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());;
String responseString = response.body();
if (!responseString.contains("Invalid")) {
      type = AccType.VALID;
}
```

**The imports that I use**

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
```

**What I have tried**

Setting the proxy directly from the client object using the proxy method
Using different imports (Did not work well with the rest of the import)
Random solutions I have tried my self

**Notes**

- I am trying to keep the program running as fast as possible
- I have spent countless hours attempting to find a solution
- This is for educational purposes, I am not going to be releasing this anywhere
- Please be nice to me

Comment: does anyone have any sort of solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Documentation

1. The java doc has usage example for HttpClient with proxy
2. [HttpClient Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html)

### Usage

```java
    HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("your proxy host", your proxy port as integer)))
        .build();
```

If you have auth issues with proxy, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333556/proxy-authentication-with-jdk-11-httpclient)